# ubuntu 14.04 OpenCV Installation error

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to install OpenCV on my Laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 I have Python 3 (Anconda 3)

I am getting a lot of warnings /errors to do with CMake amongst other things.
The error which causes the abortion of the installation seems to be with Python 3 (Anaconda)

Below is a excerpt from of the problem with CMake

```
[ 27%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles`     /opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_reduction.cu.o`
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]
```

Many other problems similar to this

The problem that happens just before the installation fails is:

```
//home/brendan/anaconda3/lib/libQtGui.so.4: undefined reference to `png_set_text@PNG16_0'
//home/brendan/anaconda3/lib/libQtGui.so.4: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16@PNG16_0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_cudev] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Restoring overwritten files from backup...OK

Cleaning up...OK
```

Regards

Brendan

Comment: Have you tried installing and linking libpng/libpng-dev manually?

Comment: also make sure the configure didn't produce any errors before starting the make process and resolve them first

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to python and I dont really use Linux in much depth either I had tried to reinstall c make and I got the "install" to go so far until I got a different error this time bus still at 50 Percent of the install

Comment: I am not sure how to manually link libpng/libpng-dev manually? I am not sure what you mean when you say have you configured it? I get so many error I would not know where to start. I think part of the problem is that I have two versions of python.  but when it stops the installation it is when it is a problem with cuda?